# Copy contents of a smart folder to a new folder in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, bash, folders, smart-folders, file

I admit that my music collection is a royal mess. This is the result of merging many sources of music (external drive, old iPod sync, iTunes purchases, etc) into my iTunes account. iTunes Match has done a pretty good job of cleaning it up visually as I look at it in iTunes.

What I want to do is create a backup copy of all my music no matter where it lives (external HD, etc.) to one location and hopefully eliminate duplicates in the process.

More specifically, I setup a smart folder to find all of kind:music with a bitrate over 44kbps. This results in over 20,000 music files at around 485 GB. I now want to copy all this content to my external drive to ensure I have a backup of all these audio files.

I tried a simple select all and drag to copy, but that didn't seem to work. After a few days of Finder "not responding", I killed the process.  Some zero-byte files were created on the external drive, but no sign of progress after the first few minutes.

I'm wondering if there is a Terminal command that could reference the contents of a smart folder and copy or some other creative way to get this done.

I really don't want to mess with iTunes, I just want to copy all music files to the external HD. Bash script maybe?

Comment: Copying over 485 GB would definitely take a long time, probably 3 days at normal iMac write speeds. It would be good to divide the files into groups of about 10 GB, and work with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mdfind` in a shell script to simulate your smart folder's settings (mdfind is how you use Spotlight from the command line). Use `kMDItemKind` to specify the kind and `kMDItemAudioBitRate` for the bitrate.

Then you can use that list of files and copy them to your external drive.

Something like this script below. (`scp` copies files to a server; use `cp` to copy to a drive. Or, if you want to get fancy, `rsync` is generally better for incremental backups.)

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in $(mdfind 'kMDItemAudioBitRate >= "44000"')
do
    scp $FILE myname@myserver:~/music-backup
done
```

Comment: kMDItemKind didn't work, but after some digging, I found that kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.audio does work.  This lists all audio file types, so may be too broad for some.

Comment: @knipknup Yeah, I poked around with kMDItemKind and the only way I could get it to work properly was to make a Smart Folder in the Finder, choose "Kind = Music" and copy the number that it saves in the file.